# How to get value of table cell with jquery from checkbox using absolute row number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table 'mytable' that looks like:

```
 <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="11"></td>   
      <td>11</td>
      <td>2014-11-06 18:49:26</td>
      <td>MESSAGE</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>MATCH5</td>
      <td>NO MATCH</td>
      <td>NO MATCH</td>
 </tr>
```

I want to get the value of column 4 "MESSAGE" from a row if its checked

as you can see each row begins with a checkbox which  have a value. however the value is non-sequential so I can't just go with the checkbox value (which I have been getting with

```
var IDs = $('input:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();)
```

I need some way of counting table rows then I can use something like:

```
 var id= $("#myTable tr").eq(ID).find('td').eq(4).val()
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close but consider what `this` is in the context of `map()`.

`this` is the checkbox that is checked. From there you can find the closest `tr` and then the `td` with the 3rd 0-based index, and then get the `text()` of that `td`. `td` doesn't have a `value` so use `text` instead.

```
var ids = $('table input:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that almost works , I'm getting: Object["MESSAGE"] How can I get just the text/html

Comment: var ids = $('table input:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
}).get();