# How to get the value out of Object[value] in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table 'mytable' that looks like:

```
 <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="11"></td>   
      <td>11</td>
      <td>2014-11-06 18:49:26</td>
      <td>MESSAGE</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>MATCH5</td>
      <td>NO MATCH</td>
      <td>NO MATCH</td>
 </tr>
```

I want to get the value of column 4 "MESSAGE" from a row if its checked. In [How to get value of table cell with jquery from checkbox using absolute row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788050/how-to-get-value-of-table-cell-with-jquery-from-checkbox-using-absolute-row-numb) it was shown that

```
var ids = $('table input:checked').map(function(){
  return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
});
```

returns

```
Object["MESSAGE"]
```

How can I get just the contained text/html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `get()` at the end, to get an array. The values will be in that array.

```
var ids = $('table input:checked').map(function(){
  return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
}).get();
```

Otherwise, you just have a jQuery collection pointing to a bunch of strings.